# vcfutils for parsing multiple vcf files

Tags: python

I have multiple VCF files and What I need to achieve is to extract some rows from VCF file based on the defined filters.. So in order to achieve that I started off with using

```
import vcf
import vcf.utils
```

which seems to be to straight forward and neat. but I am getting issues, in between it would be really great if some one take a look and guide a little bit to get to the desired output..

VCF file looks like this its has lines starting with # and later information we needed,(few lines with headers and the rows needed are as follows,)

```
##fileformat=VCFv4.1
##source=V2
##INFO=<ID=DP,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Total depth of quality bases">
##INFO=<ID=SOMATIC,Number=0,Type=Flag,Description="Indicates if record is a somatic mutation">
##INFO=<ID=SS,Number=1,Type=String,Description="Somatic status of variant (0=Reference,1=Germline,2=Somatic,3=LOH, or 5=Unknown)">
chr10   197523  .   G   A   .   PASS    DP=26;SS=1;SSC=2;GPV=5.4595E-6;SPV=6.1327E-1    GT:GQ:DP:RD:AD:FREQ:DP4 0/1:.:17:8:9:52.94%:5,3,4,5 0/1:.:9:4:5:55.56%:2,2,2,3
chr10   198411  .   T   G   .   PASS    DP=37;SS=1;SSC=5;GPV=1.2704E-5;SPV=2.7151E-1    GT:GQ:DP:RD:AD:FREQ:DP4 0/1:.:19:13:6:31.58%:8,5,1,5    0/1:.:18:9:8:47.06%:3,6,5,3
```

and so I used following piece of python code to get the information I need,

The flowing piece of code throws error message,

```
reader_BM_CR_ID = vcf.Reader(filename="sample/sam/sample.vcf", compressed=False)
writer_CR = vcf.Writer(open('same/sam/sample_filtered.vcf', 'w'), reader_BM_CR_ID)
 for variants in vcf.utils(reader_BM_CR_ID):

     for call in variants.samples:
           if call.sample == 'T':
                if call.data.FREQ >='20%':
                    if call.data.FREQ >'0%':
                         if call.data.FREQ !='100%':
                                if call.data.DP >=20:
        writer.write_record(id_var)
```

The error message,

```
        TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-471-526e4c3bbab1> in <module>()
----> 1 for variants in vcf.utils(reader_BM_CR_ID):
      2 
      3          for call in variants.samples:
      4                if call.sample == 'T':
      5                     if call.data.FREQ >='20%':

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Any help is really appreciated..!!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call `module` as `function`.

Python carefully reports about it:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: Thanks, Can u suggest a solution to get rid of it..and that would help better